# ReactDOM is not rendering to dom

Tags: reactjs

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id='app'></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my index.js === bundle.js(webpack)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I got an error in console

> ERROR in ./~/react-dom/index.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>    resolve module 'react/lib/ReactDOM' in
>    E:\react_redux\react-redux\node_modules\react-dom @
>    ./~/react-dom/index.js 3:17-46

and my package.json

```
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-dom": "15.0.2",
```

Comment: If you are new and haven't seen it, maybe try create-react-app to to see proper setup of a react app and have a nice starting point.

Comment: thanku boss and i will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You request react of at least version 15.5.4, and react-dom of exactly version 15.0.2.  They will not work with each other.

```
"react": "^15.5.4", 
"react-dom": "15.0.2",
```

Request react-dom version matching react version:

```
"react": "^15.5.4", 
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
```

Comment: After you fix that, you will run into problem that @xyious noticed.

Comment: thanku soooo much sir and i figure out after that i have to change root to app. actually mu code was different . during debugging i copy paste that from react-router documentation